# jquery append not appending a styled icon properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

so I obtained a piece of html code from a PHP site that returns the following:

```
<span class="inline-icon link-icon with-fav" style="background: url("/system/files/imagecache/s_favicon/attachments/links/favicons-201203/1d5920f4b44b27a802bd77c4f0536f5a_48.png?1332860368") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"></span>
```

and then I appended it to a page using javascript

```
$('.container').append(variableContainingTheStringAbove);
```

but then the icon does not display properly and when I inspected element using firebug, the thing instead displays like this:

```
<span class="inline-icon link-icon with-fav" transparent;"="" 0%="" scroll="" no-repeat="" 1d5920f4b44b27a802bd77c4f0536f5a_48.png?1332860368")="" favicons-201203="" links="" attachments="" s_favicon="" imagecache="" files="" system="" style="background: url("></span>
```

what could have possibly gone wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily spotted once syntax coloring is applied -- you need to use single quotes in your inline style instead of nested double-quotes.

```
<span class="inline-icon link-icon with-fav" style="background: url('/system/files/imagecache/s_favicon/attachments/links/favicons-201203/1d5920f4b44b27a802bd77c4f0536f5a_48.png?1332860368') no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"></span>
```

Better yet, use an external class instead of inline styles at all.